# Using code, how to sync data from CRM online 2011 to sharepoint online 2011 (or 2013) & vice-versa

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-online, bcs, dynamics-crm, azure

I am trying for a proof-of-concept on this one.

I have a sample crm-online plugin and I would like to know if through the code I can open my sharepoint online site and thereby get access to the lists/documents in sharepoint site.

I don't see any article or MSDN links that talks about using sharepoint object model or sandbox solution within CRM plug-in (crm online).

Same way I would like to have some form in Sharepoint online and pass the data from sharepoint online to crm online.

Hope someone replies with their thoughts and any success stories. Currently the only other option I have seen is the route of windows azure but that's an other investment for customer and requires more work as well.

Here are the sample codes (crm plug-in) I am trying.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509030.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594416.aspx

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I just asked a similar question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87496/is-it-possible-to-retrive-crm-online-data-from-sharepoint-online-using-javascrip