# Is it possible to retrive CRM online data from SharePoint Online using javascript?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin, dynamics-crm

So I would like to get data from Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Online into my SharePoint Online SharePoint Hosted App.

Is this possible to javascript only?

- Can I use the same Cross Origin Query mechanism for accessing CRM online data, as I use when I access the host web ( SP.RequestExecutor.js )?
- Is the same authentication mechanism used? (Yes, there seem to be single sign on on both sites, but still)

Thanks for any thought on this

Comment: If you have single sign on, this is actually quite easy I have done it myself. The CRM data uses its own special query rules so I would look at that though before you take on this endevour.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg985387.aspx

This is really a CRM question not a SharePoint one though